# Python Regex to capture from txt file

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex that will match a string only if the string consists of two capital letters (state abbreviations) and the constraints.

The txt file has the following partial values:

```
VARS 
WA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ID : 1 2 3 4 5 
OR : 1 2 3 4 5 
NV : 1 2 3 4 5 
CA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ENDVARS 
CONSTRAINTS 
!= WA OR 
!= WA ID 
!= CA OR 
!= MA RI 
!= MA CT 
!= CT RI 
ENDCONSTRAINTS
```

I got stuck at `([A-Z]+)` and the cheat sheet is not helpful. I am trying to get two sets:
Set 1: Capture (not including the words VARS and ENDVARS)\

```
 WA : 1 2 3 4 5
 ID : 1 2 3 4 5
 OR : 1 2 3 4 5
 NV : 1 2 3 4 5
 CA : 1 2 3 4 5
```

Set 2: Capture (not including CONSTRAINTS and ENDCONSTRAINTS)\

```
 != WA OR 
 != WA ID 
 != CA OR 
 != MA RI 
 != MA CT 
 != CT RI
```

I thought adding `{2}` will mean capturing only 2 characters, for th first set, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the boundary condition for the regex.

You have figured out that its `[A-Z]{2}` but you also want to ensure that the words are starting and ending and that you have a space after that. To do that, you can do `\b[A-Z]{2}\b` . You can review this in the [reg101](https://regex101.com/r/nwVDMJ/1) link.

First I am trying to find out which set the next set of data would be for. If the set has VAR, then the flag for VAR is set. If the data starts with CON, then the flag for CON is set. The assumption is that the following lines will be part of the VAR or CON set.

```
import re
var = "VAR"
var_set = []
con = "CONSTRAINTS"
con_set = []
with open('abc.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        line = line.strip()
        z = re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]{2}\b ",line)

        if not z:
            if   var in line: found = var
            elif con in line: found = con
            else: found = '' 

        if z:
            if found == var:
                var_set.append(line)
            elif found == con:
                con_set.append(line)

print ('var set')
for v in var_set: print (v)
print ('con set')
for c in con_set: print (c)
```

The output of this will be:

```
var set
WA : 1 2 3 4 5
ID : 1 2 3 4 5
OR : 1 2 3 4 5
NV : 1 2 3 4 5
CA : 1 2 3 4 5
con set
!= WA OR
!= WA ID
!= CA OR
!= MA RI
!= MA CT
!= CT RI
```

You may also be interested in reviewing the example I did for similar situation. See Stack Overflow solution : [Extract line from txt file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679770/extract-line-from-txt-file-using-python/65680588#65680588)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these two work for your input file.

**Part 1**

Two capitals, a space, a colon, a repetition of spaces and digits

```
[A-Z]{2} :[ 0-9]+
```

Matches:

```
WA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ID : 1 2 3 4 5 
OR : 1 2 3 4 5 
NV : 1 2 3 4 5 
CA : 1 2 3 4 5
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQPOQ2/1)

**Part 2**

Exclamation mark, equal sign, space, a repetition of spaces and capitals

```
!= [ A-Z]+
```

Matches:

```
!= WA OR 
!= WA ID 
!= CA OR 
!= MA RI 
!= MA CT 
!= CT RI
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jtF1lb/1)

Comment: Thank you. Silly me, I am forgetting the space, no wonder why I am initially capturing just the alpha characters.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

txt = '''\
VARS 
WA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ID : 1 2 3 4 5 
OR : 1 2 3 4 5 
NV : 1 2 3 4 5 
CA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ENDVARS 
CONSTRAINTS 
!= WA OR 
!= WA ID 
!= CA OR 
!= MA RI 
!= MA CT 
!= CT RI 
ENDCONSTRAINTS
'''

print([m for m, _ in re.findall(r"([A-Z]{2}\s:\s(\d\s)+)", txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)])
# ['WA : 1 2 3 4 5 ',
#  'ID : 1 2 3 4 5 ',
#  'OR : 1 2 3 4 5 ',
#  'NV : 1 2 3 4 5 ',
#  'CA : 1 2 3 4 5 ']
print([m for m, _ in re.findall(r"(!=\s([A-Z]{2}\s)+)", txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)])
# ['!= WA OR ', '!= WA ID ', '!= CA OR ', '!= MA RI ', '!= MA CT ', '!= CT RI ']
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you, I thought of starting with how to capture what I need and I am about to get to what you just suggested. I will eventually go the backtracking search and color mapping. looks like this is a step closer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

U can split the problem into two sets of patterns. The first one looks for starting variables and ending in numbers and the second one skips the first values and ends in a letter.

```
import re

pattern_1 = r'^[A-Z]{2}(?=\s).*\d'
pattern_2 = r'^.{1,2}\s[A-Z]{2}\s\w*'

data = """
VARS 
WA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ID : 1 2 3 4 5 
OR : 1 2 3 4 5 
NV : 1 2 3 4 5 
CA : 1 2 3 4 5 
ENDVARS 
CONSTRAINTS 
!= WA OR 
!= WA ID 
!= CA OR 
!= MA RI 
!= MA CT 
!= CT RI 
ENDCONSTRAINTS
"""

group_1 = re.findall(pattern_1, data, re.MULTILINE)
print(group_1)
>>> [
  'WA : 1 2 3 4 5', 
  'ID : 1 2 3 4 5', 
  'OR : 1 2 3 4 5', 
  'NV : 1 2 3 4 5', 
  'CA : 1 2 3 4 5'
]

group_2 = re.findall(pattern_2, data, re.MULTILINE)
print(group_2)
>>> [
  '!= WA OR', 
  '!= WA ID', 
  '!= CA OR', 
  '!= MA RI', 
  '!= MA CT', 
  '!= CT RI'
]
```