# Extract specific lines which changes in different text files

Tags: python, line, extract

I'm searching for a good way to extract specific lines from multiple text files. The lines I want to extract are not always the same line numbers etc.

I want to extract the Team + Team members.

Textfiles can look like that:

**Example 1:**

```
some other lines

Team 2
   dff30000 player1 (Random)
   dff30001 player2  (USA Airforce)
Team 3
   1AA6E030 player3  (Random)
   1AB6E030 player4  (China Nuke)

some other lines
```

**Expected output Example 1:**

```
team2 = ["player1", "player2"]
team3 = ["player3", "player4"]
```

**Example 2:**

```
some other lines

Team 1
   dff30000 player2 (USA Airforce)
   dff30001 player3  (China Infantry)
   dff30002 player5  (GLA)
Team 4
   1AA6E030 player1  (Random)
   1AB6E030 player4  (Random)

some other lines
```

**Expected output Example 2:**

```
team1 = ["player2", "player3", "player5"]
team4 = ["player1", "player4"]
```

**Example 3:**

```
some other lines

Team 3
   dff30000 player2 (Random)
Team 4
   1AA6E030 player1  (Random)

some other lines
```

**Expected output Example 3:**

```
team3 = ["player2"]
team4 = ["player1"]
```

**Example 4:**

```
some other lines

No Team
   dff30000 player1 (Random)
   1AA6E030 player2 (Random)
   1ABBE030 player3 (Random)


some other lines
```

**Expected output Example 4:**

```
no_team = ["player1", "player2", "player3"]
```

**Update:**
Full example data you can find here: https://www.gentool.net/data/zh/2022_01_January/22_Saturday/
(in every folder the txt-files)

**Update 2:**
Added Example 4 for "No Team"

Comment: You know you could do this with grep/egrep '(^Team|player[0-9])', right? (assuming you prefer to do it in Python.) Also, please fill in actual text for the contents of 'Random', does it contain whitespace and punctuation, will it show up as multiple columns, can it contain the magic strings 'Team' or 'player'...

Comment: I want to do this with python cause I extract the data and put in in a elasticsearch to visualize it with kibana. Thats working already but without the teams.
The "columns" are <id> <playername> <(army)>
No special characters there.

Comment: See if this answer helps you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679770/extract-line-from-txt-file-using-python/65680588#65680588

Answer (score 2):

Since the data you need is in the same position after a team name, you could loop through it and store the team name in the variable `team_num` and initialize a key in a dictionary as a `list`. Then you could append the respective elements to the current key.

```
with open("data.txt") as file:
    data = file.readlines()

data = [d.strip() for d in data]

data_dict = {}
team_num = ""
for line in data:
    if "Team" in line:
        team_num = line
        data_dict[team_num] = []
    else:
        data_dict[team_num].append(line.split()[1])

print(data_dict)
```

Input:

```
Team 2
   dff30000 player1 (Random)
   dff30001 player2  (Random)
Team 3
   1AA6E030 player3  (Random)
   1AB6E030 player4  (Random)
```

Output:

```
{'Team 2': ['player1', 'player2'], 'Team 3': ['player3', 'player4']}
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly for the given example but I forgot to meantion the bevore and after the team block can be other lines. Then the example not working (added "some lines" in my original post)

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to iterate through the lines of a file and use regular expressions to extract data to a dictionary:

```py
teams = {}

with open('data.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        m = re.match(r'Team \d+$', line)
        if m:
            name = m.group()
            teams[name] = []
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                m = re.match(r' +\w+ +(\S+)', line)
                if not m: break
                teams[name].append(m.group(1))
                line = f.readline()
        else: line = f.readline()   
                     
print(teams)

# {'Team 1': ['player2', 'player3', 'player5'], 'Team 4': ['player1', 'player4']}
```

`re.match` only matches if the supplied regex pattern matches from the start of the string.

You can get a detailed breakdown of the regex by entering them at [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. Just needed to edit the Regex cause I forgot an example with "No Team" (added it).
My Regex:         m = re.match(r'(No Team)|(Team \d+)$', line)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? I think it should work.

data.txt:

```
some other lines

Team 1
   dff30000 player2 (USA Airforce)
   dff30001 player3  (China Infantry)
   dff30002 player5  (GLA)
Team 4
   1AA6E030 player1  (Random)
   1AB6E030 player4  (Random)

some other lines
```

Code #1:

```
with open('data.txt', mode='r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

output = {}
TeamFlag = False # Not reading any team information

for line in data:
    # Stop if we encounter an empty line while reading team information
    if TeamFlag and line.strip() == "":
        break
    if "Team" in line: # Create a team
        TeamFlag = True # Remember that we started reading team information
        team = f'team{line.split()[1]}'
        output[team] = []
    elif TeamFlag: # Check if we are still reading team info, then add player info.
        output[team].append(line.split()[1])
    else: 
        continue

# Print output in required format
for team, players in output.items(): 
    print(f'{team} = {players}')
```

Output #1:

```
team1 = ['player2', 'player3', 'player5']
team4 = ['player1', 'player4']
```

Here's a simpler implementation assuming player info always contains the term "player" like player1, player2, etc (similar to team info always containing the term "Team").

Code #2:

```
with open('data.txt', mode='r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

output = {}

for line in data:
    if "Team" in line: # Create a team
        team = f'team{line.split()[1]}'
        output[team] = []
    if "player" in line: # Add player info
        output[team].append(line.split()[1])


# Print output in required format
for team, players in output.items(): 
    print(f'{team} = {players}')
```

Output #2:

```
team1 = ['player2', 'player3', 'player5']
team4 = ['player1', 'player4']
```